# Help in adding camera into Proteus 8

Tags: arduino, camera, proteus

I wish to make an Arduino model in Proteus 8 for simulating it before purchasing the components. I wish to include an OV7670 camera. But I can't find any library for it anywhere. So, my questions are:

1. How can I make custom components (created in Proteus), act like the camera?
   or
2. Is there any available library that can help?

All suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Proteus, but what would you expect to learn from a camera simulation? I would expect that you could model it with a quiescent load and an active load. This could be simulated using two resistors and a switch.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.